Android Push Notification even the app is fully ended
I'm really new to java, and I want to make a reminder app, and I am currently stuck on sending a notification to the user when user's app is fully closed (Destroyed). Please help me, would be a much appreciate
My MainActivity
package com.example.notificationtest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.PackageManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    String medicineName = "Medicine";


    
    String dayTime = "Mon, 13:27:00";
    Date timeSet;
    Date date1;
    Boolean running = true;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.notify);

        // Checking the Version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            // Check if permission is enabled or not
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // If Permission is NOT Granted Ask for permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 101);
            }
        }

        // Formatter
        SimpleDateFormat dayformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, HH:mm:ss");

        try {
            timeSet = dayformatter.parse(dayTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Log.d("Date Formatter", "" + timeSet + " \n" + date1);

        
    }
    
    // Notification Function
    public void makeNotification() {
        String chanelID = "CHANNEL_ID_NOTIFICATION";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), chanelID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_alarm_24)
                .setContentTitle("Medicine Reminder")
                .setContentText(String.format("Hey! It's time to take your medicine! %s", medicineName))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("data", medicineName);
        
        // When notification is clicked
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        
        // When the android version is higher than OREO, Set the Channel ID
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(chanelID);
            if (notificationChannel == null) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(chanelID, "Some Description", importance);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }

        if(date1.after(timeSet)) {
            Log.d("user alarm", "Ring");
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
            running = false;
        }
    }


}




Make the code send the user notification even though app is closed
Can you also explain it how it works easily please


For local push notifications even when the app is closed, you need to use alarm manager and use the local push notification code in the block of the alarm manager. Below is the documentation that you can follow.
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule

To send a notification when your Android app is fully closed (Destroyed), you can use a BroadcastReceiver combined with AlarmManager or WorkManager. Briefly:

Create a notification channel.
Implement a BroadcastReceiver that handles the notification logic, and register it in the AndroidManifest.xml.
Schedule the notification using AlarmManager, for periodic tasks, use WorkManager.
The AlarmManager is suitable for setting exact alarms, while WorkManager is better for background tasks over a long period.

For more info please see the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
